# I can not edit a pimcore data object importer configuration

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-datahub

I want to work with the data importer feature of pimcore.

For testing I have installed a new local instance of pimcore skeleton. The version is the newest one V11.0.7.

After that I followed the documentation of pimcore:
I have installed the datahub. I can see the icon and can add / edit a new GraphQL configuration.
After that I have installed the data importer.
`composer require pimcore/data-importer`
I have edited the `config/bundles.php` and installed the bundle with `bin/console pimcore:bundle:install PimcoreDataImporterBundle`
The `composer require pimcore/admin-ui-classic-bundle` I had already done with the installation of the datahub.

If I check the installed bundles with `bin/console pimcore:bundle:list` the result is that the PimcoreDataHubBundle and the PimcoreDataImporterBundle is enabled and installed.

Now I can add a Data object Importer configuration in the Datahub in the pimcore admin backend. I can see the new created configuration. But if I click on it to edit the configuration nothing happens.

[Screenshot of the new created configuration without the possibility to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLNMR.png)

The user I am using is an admin user.

There is no error in the dev.log, neither in the network tab of the browsers developer console.

The feature works in the pimcore demo in their website. Because of that I guess I have forgotten anything but I don't know what.

This is my config/bundles.php

```
<?php

use Pimcore\Bundle\DataHubBundle\PimcoreDataHubBundle;
use Pimcore\Bundle\DataImporterBundle\PimcoreDataImporterBundle;

return [
    Pimcore\Bundle\SimpleBackendSearchBundle\PimcoreSimpleBackendSearchBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Pimcore\Bundle\TinymceBundle\PimcoreTinymceBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    PimcoreDataHubBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    PimcoreDataImporterBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

And this is my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "pimcore/skeleton",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "sort-packages": true,
    "process-timeout": 0,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "symfony/runtime": true
    }
  },
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "require": {
    "pimcore/admin-ui-classic-bundle": "^1.0",
    "pimcore/data-hub": "^1.6",
    "pimcore/data-importer": "^1.8",
    "pimcore/pimcore": "^11.0.4",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^6.2",
    "symfony/runtime": "^6.2"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^5.0.3",
    "codeception/module-symfony": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "suggest": {
    "pimcore/data-hub": "Universal data interface for GraphQL, CSV and other formats"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/",
      "Pimcore\\Model\\DataObject\\": "var/classes/DataObject"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": "Pimcore\\Composer::postCreateProject",
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::postInstall",
      "@pimcore-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::postUpdate",
      "@pimcore-scripts"
    ],
    "pimcore-scripts": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::clearCache",
      "Pimcore\\Composer::installAssets"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please execute 
`php bin/console pimcore:bundle:list`
to see if you successfully activated both bundles.
https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Datahub/Installation_and_Upgrade/ https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Data_Importer/Installation